# Does acid rain do more damage or a fireball?

Tags: candy-box-2

I heard that acid rain does more because more "rain" hits, but I'm not sure if it's true.

I don't have the Red Shark Fin yet to increase damage for fireball.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The spell? Acid Rain is stronger in total but Fireball is stronger itself. Acid Rain is the winner.

Comment: The fireball spell from the grimoire.

Comment: Fireball is slightly stronger, but Acid Rain's half max damage (combining all of the hit damage, half is average) Acid Rain is stronger than Fireball.